# Calendar everyday ask enter passwords for gmail accounts

Tags: calendar, accounts, google-calendar

Everyday I see this picture on my macBook pro macOS Big Sur 11.6 (20G165)

[image: macOS calendar enter account passwords]

I enter passwords for both accounts. All works. But google send me each time Warning security emails. Then in next day i see this warnings again.

Comment: In the Calendar settings "Accounts" tab and in System Preferences -> Internet Accounts: does every account only exist one time?

Comment: @KevinGrabher yes in Calendar "Accounts" and Internet Accounts each account once. Without surprises.

Comment: Open Keychain (located in /Applications/Utilities) and search for "gmail". Delete the items listed as kind "application password", reboot your Mac, then reenter/reauth the accounts when prompted (or manually in System Preferences -> Internet Accounts)

Comment: @KevinGrabher, thanks. I tried, but it didn't help.